# Choosing between VS 2005/2008/2010 for independent learning

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working helpdesk software support on our proprietary programs.  Whenever I run into a bug, I am supposed to try and get as much info as possible so the developers can fix the source.  I have a very limited programming background but we can access the source and try and get as close to possible so the devs won't give us too much grief when we report.  The programs were written using C# 2005, ASP.NET, run using .NET 2.0, and on SQL 2005.  I am going to purchase my own copy of SQL Developer and probably Visual Studio since the company doesn't consider me a developer and won't spring for this and won't give me the company time to learn it so I need to learn it at home.

What I want to know is - should I try to get the 2005 versions, get the current 2008 version, or start on the beta 2010 versions?  Basically, if I learn all 2008/.NET 3.5/SQL 2008 or later, is there anything that will screw me up supporting older platforms - for example, not learning deprecated stuff because it is no longer in the newer versions?

10/31 - Clarifying my question - money isn't an object - SQL Dev is only $50 and I can get VS relatively cheaply.  I'm not worried about the price.  Just - if I learn the 2008 or 2010 versions of SQL/C#/ASP.NET, are there enough changes such that I'll either not understand something due to something being implemented differently?  How much change has there been - not including stuff like LINQ/MVP/WP and other frameworks which obviously won't be in the old code?

Comment: Even though you aren't worried about the price, the Express versions of SQL and VS are fully functioning & free.  You really won't be missing anything at all.  Consider it a 12 month evaluation.  Use your money to buy the 2010 edition next year.  Or take your girlfriend out to a fine restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your own personal learning, I'd recommend getting the latest stable version, in this case that would mean Visual Studio 2008, likely the free express edition.

If you are intending to work with a team or run a project that already exists, you should try as hard as possible to use the same version of Visual Studio as the project is being developed with.  I currently use Visual Studio 2005 at work most of the time, as trying to have different people using different versions of Visual Studio is nearly impossible, if only because Visual Studio will "upgrade" project files when opened in a newer version of Visual Studio, and then older versions will be unable to open them.  Beyond that, due to changes in the compiler there may be random bugs that may be introduced or hidden due to the minor changes in behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the note - I didn't realize 2008 would upgrade proj files - would really be awkward if I tried a local fix and then sent it upstream to subversion storage and created an issue.  I'll see if I can still snag a copy of VS 2k5 - I already managed to get SQL Dev 2k5.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend installing Visual Studio 2008 Express (Free).  If you want to start getting into the latest and greatest just for personal learning, also install the 2010 beta.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  If you are learning this solely to improve your ability to identify bugs in your software, learn the CURRENT language of said software, or you'll just annoy the devs more.

If you are learning for personal growth, learn the latest and (supposedly) greatest.

Comment: +1 screws the devs if they are so sensitive about their bugs.

Answer (score 2):

First don't waste money on versions of [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/) and [MSSql](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/). Go out and get the express version of Visual Studio and Sql Server.

If you are just trying to provide more information to the developers then download the current  stuff (Visual Studio 2008).

If you are interested in becoming a developer, then you want to look at 2010, since it's release is just around the corner.

Comment: Also use the newer version because it is backward-compatible enough, most of the time. For example, you can use Visual Studio 2008  (wants to target .NET framework 3.x) and reset the project targets to the previous version of .NET 2.x, which is what the developer was using in Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 2010 editions have a go-live license and a release date, I wouldn't be too concerned about using them about now. I would probably want my projects to be released after .NET 4.0 RTM though, but I would expect any last-minute changes to be easy enough to fix.

Which edition is a trick... I'd start with Express and maybe a "pro" evaluation. Of course, during the beta you can go mad and use any edition - decide whether it has features you need.

I see no benefit going 2005 - especially as 2008/2010 can multi-target. Tellingly, the 2005 express editions have been withdrawn.

I use express for odd-jobs, but I write my *real* code in VSTS; in addition to the missing *direct* features, express lacks extensibility. I use a few (not too many) VSTS addins to make development more productive.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think you ,as a new learner, should start with Visual Studio 2010. Yeah it's now Beta 2 but one day they are gonna ship full version of it so everyone start using it. Basically it wouldn't feasible to start with an older version. New version brings new features and it would be better to learn them now.

Comment: Particularly for a beginner, I'd suggest getting a version that works.  A newbie isn't going to know what goes wrong because of his mistakes or system bugs.  This means go with VS 2008 now, and wait for service pack 1 of VS2010 (VS2008SP1 was the first version we found really usable).

Comment: Alright, Although it is beta edition, there is not that much error in vs2010. Maybe you can encounter errors in depth.

Comment: I've not had VS2010 fail on me yet. But that may have something with me no having installed resharper!

Comment: Yeap, actually I am using Web Developer Express 2010 Beta 2 and it works pretty sharply. I don't want to wait Sp1 :) again.

Answer (score 0):

The 2008 adds a few useful alterations and language extensions.  It is worth getting the latest version yet learn what was added in each.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go for VS 2008 Express (such that you don't waste money on a full-blown version). VS 2008 is not only backwards compatible, but it allows you to learn the newest features such as C# 3.0 and LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VS2010 beta2...and sql express.

Than being said in way its not about the tools is about the code so you could use [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) as an IDE (and even download its source code) and a different open source database.

Also if there is a school near by and you take a class you might would qualify for the DreamSpark program.

From their website [Dreamspark Overview](https://www.dreamspark.com/FAQ/StudentOverview.aspx):

"as long as you’re a current student in a verified, accredited School and use the tools in pursuit of advancing your education in one of these areas."

&

"you must use them in pursuit of increasing your education, skills, and knowledge in either science, technology, engineering, mathematics, or design."

Since this is your own time, and nothing is being paid for by your employer you might qualify if you ever take a class.  (any MS people out there want to comment on his eligibility ??)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a nice area on MSDN called [Beginner Developer Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx). From this website you can learn about web development, desktop development, C#/Visual Basic. You can download the express versions of each type of development enviroment. Walk through tutorials, watch videos and what not. Going through the different levels of training here should get you up to speed on your independent learning.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get VS 2010 beta 2 it is really stable (have been using it for a week now !) and you will have until the end of march to chose an edition.

for learning VS2010 has all features of 2005 and 2008 and has multi target support (.net 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0) so you can chose what the framework you want to target in your case 2.0 and in the future you can shift to a new version of the framework without having to buy a new version of vs

about sql dev edition you can get it with only 40$ it has all the features of enterprise edition but it can not be used in production

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the time value of knowledge.

If you learn something how many years will you be able to use that knowledge.

Here you are just choosing between different versions of the same product, so always go with the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question starts with the premise that the purpose of this effort is to have solid bug feedback for the QA lifecycle. I would recommend you install Visual Studio 2005 and Visual Studio 2010 (currently beta 2) side by side, so that you can perform your functions with Visual Studio 2005 but learn the latest and greatest with 2010. If you can only choose one, you should choose 2005 simply because it won't try to up-convert the codebase your devs are working with (and which you're essentially QA'ing).

To answer your other question, no, there's very little trailing behind in older .NET that isn't supported and used as frequently in newer .NET. Only new stuff in new .NET.